# php array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in

Tags: php

I have tried to solve it, but I am lost. Can you see my mistake?

I have something wrong with:

```
array_push($change_data[$y],$_POST['new']['location'][$y]);
```

I get error:

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in...

`‍$‍‍y` is an integer but I need save it there. I need to create array:

```
$change_data(id => location = value)

$location_count = count($_POST['new']['id']);           
$change_data=array();  

for($y=0; $y<$location_count;$y++){ 
    if (!empty($_POST['new']['location'])) {
        array_push($change_data,$y);

        if (!empty($_POST['new']['location'][$y])) { 
            array_push($change_data[$y],$_POST['new']['location'][$y]);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $change_data[$y] is an integer not an array, if you can specify more precise how you want $change_data to look then i can give you an better answer, you current example is unclear

Comment: so I just need to write $y=array(); right?

Comment: i think you want `array_push($change_data,$_POST['new']['location'][$y]);` , this will get a new index into the array $change_data with this value ($_POST['new']['location'][$y])

Comment: `$change_data[$y]=$_POST['new']['location'][$y]` ??

Comment: Please let us know what are you trying to do? forget about `$y` and `array` and just tell us what is desired?

Comment: Looks like the whole codeblock could be replaced by `$change_data = $_POST['new']['location'];`

Comment: If you show the contents of `$_POST`, and your desired output, you should receive better answers, as it stands you question is unclear and likely to be closed

Comment: Thanks  very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're dereferencing the value and then trying to use it as an array. That won't work. Because `$change_data[$y]` gives us a scalar integer value, but `array_push` expects an array value, not a scalar value (*hence the error you're getting*).

An easier way to do this is to just assign to the array directly. `$change_data[] = $y` is semantically equivalent to saying `array_push($change_data, $y)`.

The other issue is `$change_data[$y]` may not always be what you think it is in this loop, because you're pushing to the array conditionally and `$y` increments linearly. You can't chose the key with `array_push`, but you can say `$change_data[$y] = $y`.

Finally your loop loops awkward because it makes some assumptions about [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/language.types.array) that aren't true. Namely that an array key is always a numeric value, sequentially incremented from 0.

Instead, if we actually evaluate what you're trying to do here more carefully you'll find that you're just trying to use `$_POST['new']['id']` and `$_POST['new']['location']` as an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). The more *sane* way to traverse PHP arrays and traversable objects is to use the [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) construct, which makes certain guarantees that your `for` loop here, simply does not.

Here's a simpler way to write the same code, but less prone to error.

```
$change_data = [];
foreach(array_filter($_POST['new']['id']) as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($_POST['new']['location'][$key])) {
        $change_data[$key] = $_POST['new']['location'][$key];
    }
}
```

The difference here is that the `foreach` construct guarantees that we iterate over every element in `array_filter($_POST['new']['id'])` and [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array-filter) guarantees that no element in that loop will be considered `empty()`. Since the key is tracked by `foreach` and stored in the `$key` variable we make the same adjacency list assumptions and assign directly to `$change_data` under the same key value.

Comment: Thanks  very much :)

Comment: this is what I used :)

Answer (score 1):

[PHP - array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

When you use `array_push`, it place the new element at the end of the array, you can't decide the `array key`.

Thus `array_push($change_data[$y],$_POST['new']['location'][$y]);`
should be `array_push($change_data,$_POST['new']['location'][$y]);`

If you want to decide of the key, you will do this instead:
`$change_data[$y]=$_POST['new']['location'][$y]);`

Comment: Thanks  very much :)